# Blazor: dependency injection from a class

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, blazor

I am just getting started with Blazor and web development in general and wanted to start by combining some of the console applications that I have and putting them into a Blazor web app.

The first thing I am moving over is a class that performs an API call to get organization and device count data. This class works as a console application successfully pulling the wanted data.

API call class:

```
public class HuntressAPI
{
    public static async Task Huntress()
    {
        string apiUrl = "url";
        string username = "username";
        string password = "password";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(jsonResponse);

                    if (apiResponse.Organizations != null && apiResponse.Organizations.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DisplayOrganizations(apiResponse.Organizations);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No organizations in the response.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DisplayOrganizations(List<Organization> organizations)
    {
        foreach (var organization in organizations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Organization Name: {organization.Name} | Agent Count: {organization.agents_count}");
        }
    }

    public class Organization
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int agents_count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my `Program.cs` I have `builder.Services.AddTransient<HuntressAPI>();` to add the dependency.

In the Razor page I have `@inject HuntressAPI huntress`. In the Razor page I am trying to add information to a table and when I try and access the `HuntressAPI` class I am not getting any objects.

`Licenses.razor`:

```
@page "/licenses"
@inject HuntressAPI huntress

<h3>Licenses</h3>

<p>Shows the current licensing count of the services</p>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Site Name</th>
            <th>Huntress</th>
            <th>Total Count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @huntress.
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
}
```

Is there something I am missing as this is my first time with dependency injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done for making a good attempt at setting up well-structured code. Aside from a couple of minor issues, you were doing pretty well until the last step.

You need to return data from your HuntressAPI methods that can be used by the razor page. (I would also recommend non-static methods, but that is another post).

```cs
public class HuntressAPI
{
    // Return your mapped data type from the method
    public async Task<List<Organization>> Huntress()
    {    
        // API request and response mapping
        // omitted for brevity
        string jsonResponse = await GetJsonResponse();    
        // this method will map the json response to 
        // whatever data type you want to return
        List<Organization> apiResponse = MapJsonResponse(jsonResponse);
        return apiResponse;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetJsonResponse()
    { 
      // TODO: get data from API
    }  

    private async Task<List<Organization>> MapJsonResponse(
      string jsonResponse)
    {
      // TODO: implement
    }
}

public class Organization
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int agents_count { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have injected your class into your razor component, you need to call the class method that makes the API call and returns the data. You will want to use Blazor's [lifecycle events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to make calls to your class at the appropriate time.

In your case you probably want to load the data when the page first loads. For this you would override the `OnInitializedAsync` method to make the call when the component first loads.

You will also need to store the results of the call in a property that your HTML can use.

```cs
@*Render the data here*@
@if (Organizations != null)
{
  @foreach (var organization in Organizations)
  {
    <div>@organization.Name</div>
  }
}

@inject HuntressAPI HuntressAPI
@code {
  private List<Organization> Organizations {get; set;}
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
     // load the data when the component first loads
     // and store it in a property
     Organizations = await HuntressAPI.Huntress();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is a lot there that is beyond my current understanding and giving me more to look into (I have only been in C# for 2 months now and still really new). What is the purpose of the MapJsonResponse and GetJsonResponse? I am not quite sure what all would need to go in there. Would I just move my JSON logic that I originally had in my Huntress() class?

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to keep my example cleaner to show what had changed. I omitted the bits that you clearly already know how to do. In general I would advise breaking your code down into smaller chunks anyway, but my methods were more of a hint than an instruction.

Comment: Ultimately you want your method to return the mapped version of the API response. How you do that is up to you. Well done on your efforts so far.

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to get this all organized and working currently. Should I have another class for the actual API calling?

Comment: The reason I suggest breaking your code down into smaller chunks is that you simplify the code into simple data in, data out chunks (often referred to as units). This makes it easier for you to understand what's going on in each section of the code. You can then link all of these chunks together to make your program. Remember - not only do you want to instruct the computer - it's arguably more important that your code is easy to understand for other humans (including your future self)

Comment: "Should I have another class for the actual API calling". At this point I think you should just get something working. I would focus on that first and then think about structure. As you get more experienced you will automatically have a good idea about how to structure it.

Comment: Thank you for all the help Kurt! I was able to get the data to render on the razor page successfully!

Comment: Fantastic! Happy c sharping